# Spark not able to access S3 when run standalone on AWS Batch

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-ecs, aws-batch

With the AWS library I can access S3, but if I try to access S3 with Spark program (build with NativePackager) this doesn't work.

I tried s3://, s3n:// and s3a://.

Let me show a few off my tests:

**test 1:**

If I do nothing special. Failed as described before.

**test 2:**

Following https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html, I did this code before invoking my code:

```
curl --location http://169.254.170.2/$$AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI > credentials.txt
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=`cat credentials.txt | perl -MJSON::PP -E 'say decode_json(<>)->{"AccessKeyId"}'`
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=`cat credentials.txt | perl -MJSON::PP -E 'say decode_json(<>)->{"SecretAccessKey"}'`
```

The some error has before

**test 3:**

If I set the AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY with my personal keys. Both AWS library and Spark Work

Considering that the **test 3** works, my code works. For obvious reason, I don't like to maintain keys around. The question is:

*How can I use the AWS Batch (ECS) created credentials on my Spark Job?*

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and after reading the [documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.0/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html#Changing_Authentication_Providers) carefully I realized I needed to add this to my spark properties:

```
sparkConf.set('spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider', 'com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain')
```

Hope it helps